# Пишу код для игрока ,но в коде высвечивает ошибку CS0103. Не могу понять в чём ошибка

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float speed;
   public float jumpForce;
   private float moveInput;

   private Rigidbody2D rb;

   private bool facingRignt = true;   

   private void Start()
   {
       rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    
   }


   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
       moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
       rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
       if(facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
       {
           Flip();
       }
       else if(facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
       {
           Flip();
       }
   } 
   
   void Flip()
   {
       facingRight = !facingRight;
       Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
       Scaler.x *= -1;
       transform.localScale = Scaler;
   }
}
```

Comment: так переведи ошибку....она явно на что-то намекает..

Comment: Указывайте ошибку в теле вопроса в том числе. И также старайтесь описывать что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь

```
private bool facingRignt = true;
```

буква `c` в слове `facingRignt`  отличается от буквы, во всех её других местах использования.